# Нужно при клике выключать все чекбоксы

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется таблица с чекбоксами

```
    <table class="example1" id="example" style="width:40%;" align='center'>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="checked" type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk" value="1">
        <label for="chk1">&nbsp; 1</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="checked" type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk" value="2">
        <label for="chk2">&nbsp; 2</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="checked" type="checkbox" id="chk3" name="chk" value="3">
        <label for="chk3">&nbsp; 3</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button onclick="toggle()">Changes radio button onclick</button>
  <button onclick="on()">Change</button>
  <button onclick="off()">Off All</button>
```

И js

```
const inputs = document.querySelector("input")

const on = () => {
  inputs.checked = true;
}

const off = () => {
  inputs.checked = false;
}
```

При нажатие на on должны включаться все чекбоксы и выключаться при нажатии на off.
Не могу понять почему не получается, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

const on     = () => inputs.forEach(item => item.checked = true);
const off    = () => inputs.forEach(item => item.checked = false);
const toggle = () => inputs.forEach(item => item.checked = !item.checked);
```

```html
<table class="example1" id="example" style="width:40%;" align='center'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="checked" type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk" value="1">
      <label for="chk1">&nbsp; 1</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="checked" type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk" value="2">
      <label for="chk2">&nbsp; 2</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="checked" type="checkbox" id="chk3" name="chk" value="3">
      <label for="chk3">&nbsp; 3</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="toggle()">Changes radio button onclick</button>
<button onclick="on()">Change</button>
<button onclick="off()">Off All</button>
```